# Vertex point is returning None

Tags: postgis, sql

I have this multilinestring that has 48 NPoints. When I execute `ST_PointN(line,5)` it returns none. And to continue on, it returns None for everything after index:2 up to index:48. This is how my line looks:

```
MULTILINESTRING((-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093),(-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093,-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265),(-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265,-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985),(-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985,-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995),(-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995,-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012),(-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012,-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556),(-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556,-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124),(-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124,-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362),(-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362,-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359),(-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359,-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066),(-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522),(-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522,-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079),(-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079,-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929),(-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829,-3.16431448732505 55.9258328901507),(-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.164339 55.925777,-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001))
```

any ideas anyone what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ST_PointN will only get points from the first linestring in a multi linestring, see doc
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointN.html

What you should do is splitting the multi into single linestrings with ST_Dump. You can use the path that ST_Dump returns to identify the single linestring you want to get the points from.

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: Cool, do you know if there is a way to get the WKT of the ST_dump? I can only get the binary format..I read the doc but I do not understand how it gets the ST_AsText()..
Thanks!

Comment: SELECT ST_Astext((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) ....should work

Comment: I am trying ST_AsText(ST_Dump(%s)) but it returns an ERROR: function st_astext(geometry_dump) does not exist on character 8

Comment: alright, ST_AsEWKT() did the job. Thanks for helping me out on the ST_Dump etc.